# fast-xml-parser considers closing tag to be valid without closing bracket

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I'm trying to validate some input xml on the fly in a React app using fast-xml-parser. I'm just using the out-of-box default options, and when I try `<test></test` it comes back as valid.

Here I'm outputting the text I'm running through `parser.validate()` as well as its return value to the console:

[image]

I tried it in their online tool as well:
[image: In what world is this valid?]

Not to be rude, but am I missing a "do the right and obvious thing" switch in the options or something? I'm asking because I want to post an issue, and asking Stackoverflow first is a requirement.

Comment: For anyone coming across this before it's fixed (or a missing configuration is discovered), here's what I came up with: `const valid = !!xml && xml.trim().endsWith('>') && (parser.validate(xml) === true);`

Comment: you can use a regexp to test for a missing `>` on a closing tag: `/<(\w+)[\w\W]+<\/\1\b($|[^>])/g` . it seems your suggested code would only find the problem if it occurred on the document's closing tag.

Comment: `if((xml+"").trim().slice(-1)!=">") alert("invalid");`

Comment: Yes, I only observe the error on the closing tag at the end of the document. If there was a `<test><test2></test2</test>` it would flag the issue that the `<test2>` tag wasn't closed.

Comment: The issue has been fixed in v3.17.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It's obviously a bug...

> Not to be rude, but am I missing a "do the right and obvious thing" switch in the options or something? I'm asking because I want to post an issue, and asking Stackoverflow first is a requirement.

1. You're not being rude.  *Rude* would be to expect SO to triage bug reports (and *embarrassing* would be to require that greater attention be drawn to bugs via such a policy).
2. Note also the authors of [`fast-xml-parser`](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser) are misusing the term ***valid***.
   See [Well-formed vs Valid XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).

### ...but it's worse than an isolated bug:

From `fast-xml-parser's` [limitations section](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/fast-xml-parser#limitations):

> **Limitations**
>
> Currently FXP fails to parse XML with attributes has ">"
>   in the value. This problem is left open as change in regex for its fix
>   is degrading the performance. And the parser become very slow in case
>   of long attrbute [sic] names.

3. Any XML "parser" based on regex is a toy and should not be used professionally.

**Bottom line:** This is more serious than an isolated bug.  It's the tip of the iceberg of a serious design flaw in `fast-xml-parser`.  **Recommendation: Avoid.**